# calloc causes Bad Access

Tags: c, arrays, calloc

My `main` function has this:

```
 int main() {
  //
  double minW, minL, width, length;
  unsigned tileCap = 10;
  auto *tiles = (Tile*)calloc(tileCap, sizeof(Tile) );
  GetInput(&minW, &minL, &tiles, &tileCap);
 }
```

And my `GetInput()` will read and save into the array of `Tile`s:

```
void GetInput(double *w, double *l, Tile **tiles, unsigned *tileCap) {
  //
  printf("Tile:\n");
  double tileSize, tileJoint;
  int argc;
  unsigned tileCount = 0;

  do {
    argc = scanf("%lf %lf", &tileSize, &tileJoint);
    if (tileSize == 0 || !CorrectSize(tileSize) || !CorrectSize(tileJoint) || argc != 2)
      BadInput();

    bool needTransform = HasFloatingPoint(tileSize);
    if(needTransform) {
      tileSize = MultiplyByTen(tileSize);
      tileJoint = MultiplyByTen(tileJoint);
    }

    tiles[tileCount]->size = (long long)tileSize;
    printf("%lld\n", tiles[tileCount]->size);
    tiles[tileCount]->joint = (long long)tileJoint;

    if(++tileCount == *tileCap) {
      DoubleArray(tiles, tileCap); //f() with realloc
    }
  } while(argc != EOF);
}
```

This program works for first iteration of inputs but always gives `exit code 11` and the debugger says `BAD_ACCESS` at the assignment.

So either I'm accessing or allocating the array incorrectly.

I give my function a double pointer. So in order to access Tile members, I need to dereference it twice. One dereference is `[]` and the other one is `->`. Printing the `Tile` after assigning confirms it.

And I see nothing wrong with my allocation. Where am I wrong?

EDIT: `tiles[index]->size` would mean `*(tiles[index]).size` while I need `(*tiles)[index].size`. Dereference order and scope is important.

Comment: Please post a complete example.

Comment: Do you mean some inputs or complete functions you can copypaste?

Comment: The whole thing: a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In C, you should ***never*** use the keyword `auto`. In the context of `auto *tiles = …;`, it means the type of `tiles` is `int *`. Implicit ``int`` as banned in the last millennium (C99).   Don’t use that either. C++11 and later has other uses for `auto` and would change the discussion entirely, but this is tagged C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your code seems incomplete and I'm mostly guessing, the issue seems to be in the following line in your `main` function:

```
 GetInput(&minW, &minL, &tiles, &tileCap);
```

You should consider that `tiles` is already a pointer. When you're using `&tiles`, you're actually passing a pointer to your pointer and not the pointer itself.

In your `GetInput` function, you're using `tiles[tileCount]` which indicated you wanted to pass a pointer. If your `GetInput` was supposed to get a double pointer, you would have used `(*tiles)[tileCount]`.

You can solve many of these issues by listening

I think what you probably meant to do was:

```
 GetInput(&minW, &minL, tiles, &tileCap);
```

And the function definition should probably look like this:

```
 void GetInput(double *w, double *l, Tile *tiles, unsigned *tileCap
```

---

**EDIT:** (using a double pointer)

Since you need to use a double pointer, than you should remember to dereference the double pointer when you're looking into the data. i.e.:

```
*(tiles)[tileCount]->size = (long long)tileSize;
printf("%lld\n", *(tiles)[tileCount]->size);
*(tiles)[tileCount]->joint = (long long)tileJoint;
```

Explanation:

A double pointer needs a double de-referencing. The first dereferencing collects the information on the nested pointer (`*tiles`) and the second dereferencing collects the data (`**tiles`).

The double dereferencing can also be achieved using the square brackets (`(*tiles)[i]` or `tiles[0][i]`).

Since `tiles` is a `struct` you can use the "arrow" as the second dereferencing technique as well: `(*tiles)->size`

Comment: I need to use a double pointer because my `GetInput()` will also `realloc`. And `realloc` modifies the pointer to my understanding.

Comment: I got confused. `(*a).b` is the same as `a->b` but now I realize that I need to first dereference the the pointer. In other words I messed up my dereference order. Thank you.

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh I updated my answer to explain how to access the data in the double pointer

Comment: Yeah I messed up. `tiles[index]->size` would mean `*(tiles[index]).size` while I need `(*tiles)[index].size`.

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh - these things are part of the learning process. Good luck. As a *side note*, it's more common to use [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) in C and C++. The C++ community uses CamelCase more often than the C community. So it would be more common to name your function `get_input`... :-)  Good Luck!

Comment: @LeNguyenDuyAnh `tiles[index]->size` means `(*tiles[index]).size`, but you need `(*tiles)[index].size`. The `*` is inside of the parantheses, the difference is the closing `)`. `*(tiles[index]).size` would dereference the member `size`.